# Firebird database connection credentials

Tags: c, xcode, firebird, firebird2.5

In every program of c interface code with Firebird, I am passing the user credentials to connect to the database. If I don't pass on these credentials and directly call `isc_attach_database()` to connect to the database, Its throwing error: **Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.**

Is there a way to skip these or making these things as default. I mean I want to connect to database for each program without passing the `uname` and `password`.

Below is the sample code I use to connect to database.

```
int main()
{
    isc_db_handle db1 = NULL; // Database handle.
    isc_tr_handle   trans = NULL;//transaction handle
    // Allocate some pointers to a dpb (database parameter buffer).
    // You use the dpb to talk with the database.
    char dpb_buffer[256], *dpb, *p;

    short dpb_length;
    char *uname; // user-name.
    char *upass; // password.
    ISC_STATUS status_vector[20]; // Status vector, to monitor connection.

    char *str = "/Users/Sumanth/Desktop/NewDB2.fdb";
    uname = "SYSDBA";
    upass = "masterkey";

    dpb = dpb_buffer;

    // Specify the version of the parameter buffer, always the
    // compile-time constant isc_dpb_version1.
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_version1;

    //    # of cache buffers to allocate for use with the database,
    //   default = // 75. In the API guide I think isc_dpb_num_buffers is
    //specified as // isc_num_buffers, but that I could not get to work.
    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_num_buffers;
    *dpb++ = 1;
    *dpb++ = 90;

    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_user_name; //    Save user-name in dpb.
    *dpb++ = strlen(uname);
    for (p = uname; *p;)
        *dpb++ = *p++;

    *dpb++ = isc_dpb_password;  //   Save password in dpb.
    *dpb++ = strlen(upass);
    for (p = upass; *p;)
        *dpb++ = *p++;

    dpb_length = dpb - dpb_buffer;

    //   Attach to the database.
    isc_attach_database(status_vector, strlen(str), str, &db1,dpb_length, dpb_buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the environment variables `ISC_USER` and `ISC_PASSWORD` to connect to a Firebird database without specifying a username and password within an application. See [Setting The ISC_USER And ISC_PASSWORD Environment Variables](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-environment-variablesl). Note that the linked document only talks about the `SYSDBA` account, but it works for any account.

The Firebird Book, 2nd edition by Helen Borrie says:

> It is possible to set up the two environment variables `ISC_USER` and `ISC_PASSWORD` on the server, to avoid the need to log in when working with databases locally. You will be able do everything that the named user is allowed to do, without needing to supply credentials each time.

The text mentions *"on the server"*, but it is actually local to the client application.

The Interbase 6.0 Operations Guide (available from the [Firebird website](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/)) says:

> If you do not provide a user name and password when you connect to a database or when
> you run utilities such as **gbak**, **gstat**, and **gfix**, InterBase looks to see if the `ISC_USER` and  `ISC_PASSWORD` environment variables are set and uses that user and password as the InterBase user.
>
> Although setting these environment variables is convenient, it is strongly not
> recommended if security is at all an issue.

Comment: I have tried doing that. I set those credentials in the terminal. But, when I execute the code it still asks for credentials to connect to the database

Comment: @user3723478 Are you sure your execution environment shares these environment variables with your terminal?

Comment: Strange. I don't normally use the C API, but I looked at the firebird source code and there the username iand password is added to the dpb in the attach method. if none was provided in the dpb. I will see if I can reproduce this (might be a few days though).